# Setting default folder permissions for Apache on Fedora

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, fedora

G'day,
I have a web server running on my personal computer as a means for me to test various things.  By default, Fedora (running version 10 atm) seems to set the permission for */var/www/html/* as

```
Deny from all
```

What is the easiest way to correct this?  I have tried putting a .htaccess file in each folder, but I would much rather use some method that will apply to every folder under */var/www/html/*.  The .htaccess file I have tried using is

```
Order allow, deny
Allow from all
Deny from none
```

NOTE: I don't connect this computer to the network at all, so I don't care if "everyone" has permissions to view the folder.

Many thanks for answering.

---

EDIT: The contents of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (the relevant part) are:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow, deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

---

EDIT 2: I have found that some of the files in the folder are accessible, but not all of them - the permissions of every file are the same, but while I can access *compressed.css*, I can't access *screen.css*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have been shown the answer on linuxquestions.org (relevant posts are http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/permissions-problem-with-apache-735457/ - follow the link posted in there to see the solution that I used (have to limit myself to one link because new users can't post more than one link)).  Basically, the problem is that the SELinux context was wrong - of course, this does not show up on a normal

```
ls -l
```

but it is very easy to see with

```
ls -lZ
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you found `Deny from all` in something like `<Directory /var/www/html/>` ?
In this case you may just try to remove `Deny from all` and restart apache

Comment: I presume you are talking about /etc/http/conf/httpd.conf? I have posted the relevant part of that in my question.

Comment: This should be Ok, what kind of error are you getting ? did you check error_logs ?

Comment: Error 403 Forbidden - You don't have permission to access ... on this server